# In CakePHP 3.4 how to create subquery inside matching using fluent query builder?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Following code creates query that joins `Tasks` with latest `Decisions` trough `TasksDecisions` join table. How can I do the same without using plain query but `CriteriaBuilder` interaface??

```
 /** Root of this query object is Task
 *  Decision is direct child 
 */
 $query->matching("Decisions", function (Query $q) use ($decision) {
     $q->where(["decision IN" => $decision]);
     $q->where([
        "Decisions.id" => $q->newExpr("SELECT MAX(td.decision_id) FROM tasks_decisions td WHERE td.task_id=Tasks.id")
     ]);
     return $q;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$q->where(["Decisions.id" => $q->newExpr("SELECT MAX(td.decision_id) FROM tasks_decisions td WHERE td.task_id=Tasks.id")]);
```

try

```
$q->where(["Decisions.id" => $this->TaskDecision->find()->all();
```

This is just an example, just build the conditions as needed.

See see manual here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries